# Big Query job not found issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to move some old code that used the older google-api-client gem to the Idiomatic Ruby client google-cloud-ruby.

The process is a simple query job that saves it's results to another table. In the older gem, I used a config like this:

```
config= {
    "jobReference": {
      "projectId": GOOGLE_PROJECT,
      'location'=> 'europe-west2'
     },
    'configuration'=> {
        'query'=> {
            'allowLargeResults' => true,
            'createDisposition' => 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            'query' => sql,
            'destinationTable'=> {
                'projectId'=> GOOGLE_PROJECT,
                'datasetId'=> 'my_dataset',
                'tableId'=> table,
                'location'=> 'europe-west2'
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Following the docs for the newer library, I am running this as a basic test (the sql is defined elsewhere)

```
bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new

dataset = bigquery.dataset('my_dataset')

puts(dataset.location)

puts("1")

job = bigquery.query_job(sql, table: dataset.table(table), write: 'truncate', create: 'needed')

puts("2")

job.wait_until_done!

puts("3")

job.done?
```

This gets as far as the puts 2, failing on `job.wait_until_done!` with the error `Google::Cloud::NotFoundError: notFound: Not found: Job my_project:job_hApg5h0NQQb4Xbv7Sr3zzIXm5RWF`

If I 'puts' the job.job_id I see the same ID as it's saying it can't find. I've tried running this in datasets in multi-region and single location and still the same error. Ultimately, I need this to run on the 'europe-west2' region only.

Can anyone help and/or point me to a working example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just replicated and it worked without an issue. Can you replace your SQL to a simple `SELECT 1` and see the results? I think that it might be a NotFound error related to something in the Job , not the job itself

Comment: Hi @Raoot, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Tlaquetzal, you can replace your SQL query to a simple `SELECT 1` as below sample query and see the results.

```
sql = "SELECT 1 FROM `project.dataset.table`"
```